# What exactly were they (planning on) doing wrong here (yShabbat 16:1)?

Tags: talmud-gemara, halacha-theory

אע''פ שאמרו אין קורין בכתבי הקודש אלא מן המנחה ולמעלה אבל שונין ודורשין בהן׃ צרך דבר נוטל ובודק׃ דלמא רבי ורבי חייא רבא ור' ישמעאל בי רבי יוסה היו יושבין ופושטין במגילת קינות ערב תשעה באב שחל להיות בשבת מן המנחה ולמעלה׃ ושיירו בה אל''ף בי''ת אחד׃ אמרו למה אנו באין וגומרין אותה׃ עם כשהיה נפטר לביתו נכשל באצבעו וקרא על גרמיה  (תהילים לב)  רבים מכאובים לרשע׃ א''ל ר' חייא בחובינו מטתך כן דכתיב  (איכה ד)  רוח אפינו משיח ה' נלכד בשחיתותם׃ אמר לו רבי ישמעאל בי רבי יוסי אילו לא היינו עוסקין בעניין כך היה לנו לומר׃ על אחת כמה וכמה שהיינו עוסקין בעניין׃

The prohibition on reading Ketuvim on Shabbat until mincha has been mentioned a couple of times on the boards in answer to other questions.

([Source of saying migdol / magdil in Bentching](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/source-of-saying-migdol-magdil-in-bentching/12077#12077) and [Megilas Esther by day - why is it done after Kriyas HaTorah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/megilas-esther-by-day-why-is-it-done-after-kriyas-hatorah))

But what exactly does that prohibition entail? Since you can't read by candlelight on Shabbos either, wouldn't that mean you couldn't read Ketuvim at all? If it's just a matter of distracting people from beit hamidrash why not ban reading Torah and Nevi'im as well (aside from the kriah and haftorah)? Basically, what exactly are they supposed to be doing wrong in this story?

Answer (score 1):

This part of the question:
If it's just a matter of distracting people from beit hamidrash why not ban reading Torah and Nevi'im as well (aside from the kriah and haftorah)?

Answer:
Kesuvim are attractive to read and you get involved in them more than in other parts of Tanach as Chazal say

> שאין קורין בכתובים בשבת מפני ביטול בית המדרש **שהם מושכים את הלב**

see for example towards the end of the page [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_52079_38.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! These are fascinating. After reading these sources, though, I have a crazier question. Is it 100% clear that the prohibition on reading unfamiliar Ketuvim during the daytime hours applied only on Shabbat? I know the prohibition appears there in our sources (because it was originally a question of how this effected the status of the writings when it came to breaking Shabbat for their sake). And above story happens on Erev Shabbat. But could it be something more like the idea of learning Greek only bein hashmashot? I.e. Ketuvim are edifying/interesting but distract from real learning?

Answer (score 0):

See simply Bartenura 16, 1:

> בֵּין שֶׁאֵין קוֹרִין בָּהֶן. כְּגוֹן כְּתוּבִים, דְּאַף יְחִידִים אֵין קוֹרִין בָּהֶן בְּשַׁבָּת מִפְּנֵי בִּטּוּל בֵּית הַמִּדְרָשׁ כְּדִלְקַמָּן, שֶׁהָיוּ דּוֹרְשִׁים לָעָם בְּשַׁבָּת וּמוֹרִין לָהֶן הִלְכוֹת אִסּוּר וְהֶתֵּר, לְפִי שֶׁכָּל יְמוֹת הַחֹל הֵם עֲסוּקִים בִּמְלַאכְתָּן, וְאָסְרוּ לִקְרוֹת בִּכְתוּבִים בְּשַׁבָּת בִּשְׁעַת בֵּית הַמִּדְרָשׁ מִשּׁוּם דְּמָשְׁכֵי לִבָּא וְאָתוּ לְאִמְּנוֹעֵי מִלִּשְׁמֹעַ הַדְּרָשָׁה:‏

Reading Ketubim may be viewed as disruptive to the flow of teaching of laws. This Shabbat teaching is of prime importance because of the lack of availability of learning for most people in the rest of the week. So Chachamim prohibited to read ketubim at the time of the Drasha. Because Ketubim are very interesting and could prevent people to listen the Drasha.

See this Gemara too in Berachot 6a:

> Raba says: The crushing in the Kallah (conference) {Sometimes people are confortably seated when hearing the Shabbat Drasha and find constricted} comes from them.

There are a lot of perturbations that disturb Limud Halacha.